# Compare each value with mean in groups

Tags: r

This is my data frame:

```
id kind subject price
1 1 one 200
2 1 one 100
3 2 two 200
4 1 three 200
5 2 two 100
```

I need to add another columns with logical value comparing (for each id) price and mean of the prices inside group with the same subject. To get something like that:

```
id kind subject price less_than_mean
1 1 one 200 FALSE
2 1 one 100 TRUE
3 2 two 200 FALSE
4 1 three 200 TRUE
5 2 two 100 TRUE
```

What is the most powerful decision for large dataset?

Comment: Is the output correct?  `with(df1, price <ave(price, subject))`

Answer (score 2):

`dplyr` solution:

```
group_by(df, subject) %>%
     mutate(less_than_mean = price<=mean(price))
```

`mean` is applied separately for each group defined in the first line, and `mutate` just adds a new column. You can also do more complicated groupings by `group_by(df, subject, kind)`, for example.

Same could be done with base `tapply`, but that should be much slower than `dplyr` group operations - I believe such `dplyr` is one of the fastest solutions for large dataframes.